# Re-assigning Sets in Pyomo Models

Tags: python, pyomo

Hello I am new to Pyomo and modelling technique.

I was curious to know whether it is possible to reassign sets in the case when we continuously want to re-solve a model. For example:

```
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.m = pyo.Set(initialize=get_numbers())
```

In the example, `get_numbers()` feeds a different set every time I attempt to re-solve the model. However, I result with the following issue:

```
WARNING: Element ('x_3') already exists in Set m; no action taken
```

I found out that setting Parameters wrapped with `Param` as `mutable=True` fixes the issue. In addition removing the Set() wrapper and just calling `get_numbers()` also does the job.
However, I was interested to know whether there a correct way to properly update the set with the newest value provided by `get_numbers()` so we do not get such warnings?  Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but why don't you just make a new model?  Changing the elements of a set within a model seems like a major change that would naturally reflect a new model, unlike just changing a parameter.

Comment: That sounds as an answer actually as long as you suggest how to dynamically do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, "dynamically" could mean a few different things here.  Anytime you reassign the model variable to a new model, you make a new model, so there are several ways to do that.  Here are a few.  Both of these produce 3 independent models using the differing input values for the set `S`.  Both methods produce the same 3 models.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

my_changing_sets = [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3], ['dog', 'cat', 'pig']]

# method 1:  some kind of loop
for s in my_changing_sets:
    m = pyo.ConcreteModel('example')
    m.S = pyo.Set(initialize=s)
    m.x = pyo.Var(m.S)
    # solve or whatever...
    m.pprint()

# method 2:  build the model in a function with whatever inputs needed
def make_model(my_set):
    m = pyo.ConcreteModel('example')
    m.S = pyo.Set(initialize=my_set)
    m.x = pyo.Var(m.S)
    # solve or whatever...
    # you could return the model, the solver status, whatever...
    return m
for s in my_changing_sets:
    m = make_model(s)
    m.pprint()
```